# Visual Basic.Net Why do we need to pass size of record when opening a file in random mode?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Here, path is string and S1 is structure

code:
    `FileOpen(1, path, OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, , Len(S1))`

Why do we need to pass Len(S1) when opening a file in random mode?

Comment: How else will it know where your record ends?

Comment: won't it know when we put a record using FilePut?

Comment: FilePut() doesn't specify the record size, it specifies the record number to write.  These are ancient VB6 compatibility functions, best avoided today.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the Access Mode.
In Random-Access mode, it is the record length.
In Sequential-Access mode, it is the Buffer size.

See explain here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afh37kh8(v=vs.90).aspx

You can utilize other newer modes to open and read/write files, like Streams.

Good luck